# QFTP signals are not emitted?

Tags: c++, qt, qftp

Hi I've written a simple FTP code to upload images into a FTP server.

Now the problem is that `commandStarted(int)` and `commandFinished(int,bool)` signals never get emitted !!!

I've grabbed this code from qftp.pro which comes with Qt library and works successfully on my computer (It is a gui program) But when I put this ftp code it in my project which is a console project it fails to work !!!

My.pro

```
QT       += core network
QT       -= gui
TARGET = FTP_PROJECT
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    FTP_Class.cpp

HEADERS += \
    FTP_Class.h \
    Definitions.h
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "FTP_Class.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    FTP_Class u;
    return a.exec();
}
```

FTP_Class.cpp

```
#include "FTP_Class.h"

FTP_Class::FTP_Class(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{


    ftp = new QFtp(this);
    connect(ftp,SIGNAL(commandStarted(int)),this,SLOT(ftpStartedCommand(int)));
    connect(ftp, SIGNAL(commandFinished(int,bool)),this, SLOT(ftpCommandFinished(int,bool)));


    QUrl url("12.128.32.54");
    //if (!url.isValid() || url.scheme().toLower() != QLatin1String("ftp"))
    {
        ftp->connectToHost("12.128.32.54", 21);
        ftp->login("Hidden","[STr_9&65%Est@@]");
    }


}
void FTP_Class::ftpStartedCommand(int id)
{

    qDebug()<<"Command with ID "<<QString::number(id)<<" is started";
}

void FTP_Class::ftpCommandFinished(int, bool error)
{
    if (ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::ConnectToHost) {
        if (error) {
            qDebug()<< " Unable to connect to the FTP server Please check that the host name is correct";
            ftp->abort();
            ftp->deleteLater();
            return;
        }
    }
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Cd)
    {
        static bool enable = false;
        if(enable)
        {

        QByteArray ImAgE = ReadImage(); //reads from external library

        QString Final_Time = "Image.jpg";
        ftp->put(ImAgE,Final_Time);
        }
        enable=true;
    }
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Mkdir)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Going to dest folder";
        ftp->cd("Test");

    }
    if(ftp->currentCommand() == QFtp::Login)
    {
        ftp->cd("Image_Folder");
        qDebug()<<"creating dest folder";
        ftp->mkdir("Test");
    }
    if(ftp->currentCommand()== QFtp::Put)
    {
        if (error) {
            qDebug()<<"Error in Uploading ...";
        } else {
            qDebug("Upload is completed ...");
        }
    }
  return;
}
```

FTP_Class.h

```
#ifndef UPLOADER_H
#define UPLOADER_H

#include "Definitions.h"
class FTP_Class: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit FTP_Class(QObject *parent = 0);
QFtp *ftp;
public slots:

void ftpCommandFinished(int,bool);
void ftpStartedCommand(int id);
private:
};

#endif // UPLOADER_H
```

I can connect to my ftp server using qt sample project and also Filezilla which is an FTP client software so IP and username and passwords are okay. (for security reasons I changed username and passwords + IP in here)

What's my problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

[Using QFtp in a console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390107/using-qftp-in-a-console-app). Are you sure your program doesn't work (since it works asynchronously)? Furthermore the QT api reference suggests you should use QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply instead. See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html#details

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm pretty sure about its failure because I've debugged it in every possible way. It succeeds when I run the Qt sample project. I tried to implement it using Qnetworkaccessmanager but it also failed :(